# Twilio SMS Group functionality

Tags: twilio

So I understand that Twilio doesn't allow a single message instance between users (e.g. one SMS with multiple recipients) and that if you want to send a message to multiple people you need to send separate SMS messages (thus multiple message instances)

But is there a way to understand if an incoming message was sent to other recipients? (so that I could respond to all)

To elaborate:

1) Jane sends Bob, Ralph and me (to my Twilio number) a text message from her cell.

2) I respond to Jane (but Bob and Ralph are no longer in the conversation, unless I know they were send Jane's original message)

Can I tell from my Twilio message that Bob and Ralph were also on Jane's original thread so I can reply to all three?

I understand their replies back to me will only be back to me, but I can fool them into thinking that multiple messages are part of the original distro by sending anyone else a copy. It's suboptimal, but this is a handy feature that I think Twilio is missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid there is no way with Twilio to understand when an SMS message was sent to a group. All messages within Twilio are considered one-to-one.